# Помогите разобраться с размерами sizeof() массивов и указателей

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, sizeof

Вот вывод представленного ниже кода

```
int m[4]
 sizeof(m) is 16 byte
 sizeof(&m) is 8 byte
 sizeof(*m) is 4 byte

int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*4)
 sizeof(p) is 8 byte
 sizeof(&p) is 8 byte
 sizeof(*p) is 4 byte
```

из каждого примера мне понятны только 3-и строчки. Они означают что разыменовываем указатель идем по адресу - а там число типа int, размер которого 4 байта.

Как получилось 16 байта вроде тоже нашел ответ - что когда в sizeof стоит указатель массива - то он указывает на весь массив. поэтому 4*4 = 16 байт.
А почему все остальное по 8 байт?
И как, если я использую malloc мне в sizeof прописать так - чтобы получить кол-во выделенных байт - т.е. как получить 16 по аналогии с записью sizeof(m).

```
  int m[4];
  printf("int m[4]\n");
  printf(" sizeof(m) is %lu byte\n", sizeof(m));
  printf(" sizeof(&m) is %lu byte\n", sizeof(&m));
  printf(" sizeof(*m) is %lu byte\n\n", sizeof(*m));// здесь я понял - разименовываем, идем по адресу а там число int у которого размер 4 байта

  int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
  printf("int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*4)\n");
  printf(" sizeof(p) is %lu byte\n", sizeof(p));
  printf(" sizeof(&p) is %lu byte\n", sizeof(&p));
  printf(" sizeof(*p) is %lu byte\n", sizeof(*p));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Как получилось 16 байта вроде тоже нашел ответ - что когда в sizeof стоит указатель массива - то он указывает на весь массив. поэтому 4*4 = 16 байт.

В языке С нет понятия "указатель массива", поэтому данное объяснение - не верно.

Оператор `sizeof` возвращает размер *типа* выражения, указанного в качестве операнда. При этом особенностью `sizeof` является то, что если указанное в качестве операнда выражение имеет тип "массив", то традиционного автоматического преобразования к типу "указатель" *не производится*. (Оператор `sizeof` является примером одного из четырех особенных контекстов языка С, в которых тип "массив" не преобразуется к типу "указатель".)

Таким образом в вашем

```
sizeof(m)
```

в качестве операнда указано выражение `(m)`, имеющее тип `int[4]`. Преобразования массива `m` к типу "указатель" не происходит (и лишние скобки вокруг `m` на это не влияют), то есть данный `sizeof` вернет размер типа `int[4]`, который, как вы сами правильно заметили, равен 16.

Никаких "указателей массива" в этом процессе никак не участвует.

Ваши

```
sizeof(&m)
sizeof(p)
sizeof(&p)
```

в качестве операндов имеют выражения `(&m)`, `(p)` и `(&p)`. Все эти выражения имеют тип "указатель". В первом случае это указатель типа `int (*)[4]`, во втором - `int *`, в третьем - `int **`. Таким образом эти `sizeof` будут возвращать размеры соответствующих указательных типов. Все они на вашей платформе оказались равны 8.

Теоретически эти разнотипные указатели могут иметь разные размеры, но на практике они обычно одинаковы. Их размер определяется параметрами платформы, в т.ч. выбранной моделью памяти.

> И как, если я использую malloc мне в sizeof прописать так - чтобы получить кол-во выделенных байт - т.е. как получить 16 по аналогии с записью sizeof(m).

Никак. В языке С нет такой возможности (и `sizeof` тут совершенно ни при чем). Получить фактический размер выделенного блока памяти стандартными средствами невозможно. Это ваша задача: помнить, сколько памяти вы выделяли.

Answer (score 4):

Оператор `sizeof`  предоставляет размер в байтах заданного операнда.

Из стандарта C (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant.

В этом фрагменте кода

```
 int m[4]
 sizeof(m) is 16 byte
 sizeof(&m) is 8 byte
 sizeof(*m) is 4 byte
```

объявляется массив из четырех элементов типа `int`. Массивы в памяти хранятся в виде одного непрерывного участка.  Поэтому данное выражение с оператором `sizeof`

```
sizeof(m)
```

имеет значение равное `4 * sizeof( int )` , и если объект типа `int` имеет размер равный 4, то предыдущее выражение вернет значение равное 16.

Когда имя массива используется в операторе `sizeof`, то оно не преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент.

В данном выражении

```
sizeof(&m)
```

в операторе `sizeof` используется указатель `&m`.Следовательно будет возвращено значение объема памяти в байтах, занимаемой указателем. На вашей платформе это значение равно 8 байтам.

В этом выражении

```
sizeof(*m)
```

в качестве операнда оператора `sizeof` используется объект типа `int`, так как применение оператора * к имени массива сначала преобразует неявно имя массива в указатель на свой первый элемент массива, а затем происходит разыменование этого указателя. В результате чего будет получен этот первый элемент массива, который имеет тип int.

В этом фрагменте кода

```
 int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*4)
 sizeof(p) is 8 byte
 sizeof(&p) is 8 byte
 sizeof(*p) is 4 byte
```

объявляется указатель `p` типа `int *`. Как уже известно из анализа предыдущего фрагмента кода, указатели имеют размер, равный 8 байтам. Поэтому следующее выражение с оператором `sizeof`

```
sizeof(p)
```

на вашей платформе вернет значение равное 8.

В этом выражении

```
sizeof(&p)
```

также используется указатель, который указывает на переменную `p`, которая в свою очередь является указателем. То есть выражение `&p` имеет тип `int **`. Поэтому выражение будет иметь значение равное 8.

В этом выражении

```
sizeof(*p)
```

разыменовывается указатель. В результате выражение `*p` имеет тип `int`, и значением выражение будет число 4.

Указатели не хранят в себе информацию, адресуют ли они единственный объект или первый объект некоторого массива.

Например, в этом фрагменте кода

```
int a[10];
int x;

int *p;

p = a;
p = &x;
```

указатель `p` сначала инициализируется адресом первого элемента массива `a`, а затем его значение изменяется на адрес отдельного объекта `x`.

Поэтому если вы выделяете память динамически, то вы должны сами контролировать размер выделенной памяти. Памяти может быть выделено больше, чем требуется, или, напротив, по ошибке, меньше, чем требуется.

Функция `malloc` лишь возвращает значение адреса начала выделенного участка.

Поэтому вы можете, например, написать

```
int *p = malloc( 4 );
```

или

```
int *p = malloc( 10 );
```

или

```
int *p = malloc( 100 );
```

и работать с указателем, как будто бы он указывает на единственный объект типа `int`. Кроме самого программиста никто и ничто не будет следить, как используется выделенная память, и используется ли она корректно.

Возвращаясь к вашему второму фрагменту кода, вы могли бы объявить указатель не на объект типа `int`, а на массив, состоящий из четырех элементов типа `int`.
Например,

```
int ( *p )[4] = malloc( 4 * sizeof( int ) );
```

Тогда используя оператор sizeof к разыменованному указателю, вы получите размер массива

```
sizeof( *p )
```

равный 16 байтам.  То есть в данном случае объект, на который указывает указатель, является не объект типа `int`, а объект типа `int[4]`. Но тогда, чтобы обращаться к элементам этого массива, вам придется писать, например,

```
( *p )[i]
```

или

```
p[0][i]
```

где `i` - это некоторый индекс.

Comment: 1. `4 ( sizeof( int )` - умножение пропустил. 2. `( *0 )[i]` - что?

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо. Я исправил опечатки.

Comment: Не за что. Ещё одна: `o = &x;` :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете, скорее всего, с 64-разрядным компилятором - вот размер указателя и равен 8 байт.

Получить с помощью `sizeof` по указателю размер выделенной области памяти невозможно. Храните его отдельно.

(Если вам скажут, что как-то же помнит менеджер памяти размер выделенного блока - то да. Помнит. Но это зависит от конкретной реализации, компилятора, ОС и т.д. И, кроме того, вполне может быть, что выделено памяти больше, чем запрошено...)

Comment: подскажите а для чего пишут вот так `char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);` т.е. для чего нужно перед malloc писать (char*)

Comment: В современном чистом C не обязательно, `void*` и так приведется к `char*`. Но, думаю, такое явное приведение облегчает понимание текста - что выделяется именно для строки. Может, традиция :) Может, в расчете на использование в C++ - там приведение необходимо.

Comment: @Sibkedr: Это совершенно не нужно. Более того, в С коде это - дурная практика.